# App Crashes when TransitionStyle Changed to .Scroll

Tags: swift, uipageviewcontroller

I am attempting to change the `transitionStyle` of my PageViewControllers from `.PageCurl` to `.Scroll`. The app works fine currently with `.PageCurl` but crashes at runtime when set to `.Scroll` when you try to swipe right from `MenuViewController`.

From `RootViewController.swift` where `transitionStyle` is set:

```
self.pageViewController = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .PageCurl, navigationOrientation: .Horizontal, options: nil)
self.pageViewController!.delegate = self

let startingViewController = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MenuViewController") as UIViewController
```

The error I get is "0 swift_dynamicClassUnconditional". The breakpoint I'm pointed to for the error is in the `ModelController.swift`:

```
func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    if fromMenu == true {
        var index = self.indexOfViewController(viewController as DataViewController)
        if (index == NSNotFound) {
            return nil
        }
        if (index == 0) {
            index = experiments.count - 1
        }

        index--
        return self.viewControllerAtIndex(index, storyboard: viewController.storyboard!)
    } else {
        println("fromMenu is \(fromMenu)")
        fromMenu = true
        return self.viewControllerAtIndex(0, storyboard: viewController.storyboard!)
    }
}
```

The specific line of the error according to Xcode is

```
var index = self.indexOfViewController(viewController as DataViewController)
```

Do I need to make additional changes in order use `.Scroll`?

Comment: viewController is probably not a DataViewController, it might even be nil. Where do you set `viewControllers` of the UIPageViewController initially?

Comment: Yeah, you should `println` the `viewController` and confirm what it is. I don't see anything here unique to `.Scroll`. The `index = experiments.count - 1`, followed by `index--` seems curious (do you really mean to set it to `experiments.count - 2`?), but that doesn't seem `.Scroll` related.

Comment: Matthias, I set the `viewController` with  `viewControllerAtIndex` function. `if (self.experiments.count == 0) || (index >= self.experiments.count) {
            return nil
        }
        let dataViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DataViewController") as DataViewController
        dataViewController.experiment = self.experiments[index] as? NSDictionary
        
        return dataViewController`

Comment: Rob, the `index = experiments.count - 1` was there so to set the index as the beginning of the array so it loops back and begins again. Just realized it was unnecessary and removed it. Still crashes. How do I access the current viewController so I can print it?

Comment: @MatthiasBauch and Rob, one other data point: this app is a lightly customized version of Xcode's Page-Based Application Template. When I first starting working on it, I was able to easily toggle between .Scroll and .PageView but at some point I introduced this issue.